# Tree map method code in JavaScript about callback

Tags: javascript, dictionary, data-structures, callback, tree

I want to make a tree map method, but I can't make it. I can't understand the callback function. I don't know why you use a callback function there.

```
Tree.prototype.map = function(callback) {
  const newTree = new Tree(callback(this.value));

  function childCheck(child, newTree){
    for(let i=0; i<child.length; i++){
      newTree.addChild(callback(child[i].value))
      if(child[i].children){
        childCheck(child[i].children, newTree.children[i])        
      }
    }
  }
  childCheck(this.children, newTree)
  return newTree
  
};
```

I can't understand 'callback(this.value)' and 'callback(child[i].value)'. Why is callback used by parameter? At first, I just used 'this.value', but it isn't implemented well.
I know callback function asynchronous and it is implemented at Array.prototype.map(callback).

Comment: The callback here looks like it's used for the caller to create a newTree node,  If this function did it, then it could only ever create 1 type of treeNode..

Comment: "*I know callback function asynchronious*" - no, it's a synchronous callback. Don't you have an example of how this method is called?

Answer (score 0):

The `map` method that is defined here, provides a similar functionality as what the native `map` method provides on `Array`. The intention of `map` is to create a new data structure with the same shape, but where each value of the original data has been "mapped" (converted, translated, ...) by a given function. For instance, with an array you can do this:

```js
function double(x) {
    return x * 2;
}
let arr = [1, 2, 3];
let result = arr.map(double);
console.log(result);
```

The above snippet creates a new array which has the same number of values, but where each value is the double of the original value at that position.

If you would want to implement that `map` yourself, you would write a function that takes a function as argument. Let's for a moment assume there is no `map` method for arrays yet, then you can make a method for it:

```js
Array.prototype.myMap = function (callback) {
    let result = []; //  create a new array
    for (let value of this) {
        // create a new entry in the new array, and 
        //    give it the original value, but translated
        //    by the provided mapper (callback)
        result.push(callback(value));
    }
    return result;  // return the new array
};

// Demo of myMap:
function double(x) {
    return x * 2;
}
let arr = [1, 2, 3];
let result = arr.myMap(double);
console.log(result);
```

Now look at again at your map function for `Tree`. The function first creates a new Tree, and "maps" the original root value, so the callback is called on the original tree, so to get the translated value for the new tree's root.

Then it calls a recursive function `childCheck` which visits every other node in the original tree in a pre-order sequence. For each node it creates a new node in the new tree (at the same position) and then provides it with the value from the original node, mapped (translated) by the callback function. It is the same principle as with `Array.prototype.map`. Of course, the tree structure is a bit more complicated than a flat array structure, so it has the added complexity of doing a recursive traversal through the tree. But for the rest it really is the same principle.